# Deleting files from Media doesn't delete it from uploads folder in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, upload, media

I am deleting files from Media section in WordPress. I am permanently deleting them but they exists in /uploads/ folder.  How I can remove them from /uploads/ folder as well ??

Comment: I noticed permissions of files in /uploads/ folder are 644.

Answer (score 3):

After some research, it is caused to WPML plugin settings.
By default, the Wordpress is able to delete the file from /uploads/folder

Comment: I had the same problem today and I was searching like a fool. To add a little more details to this answer: the issue is that WPML Media plugin activates (by default I think) an option that allows the media to be used throughout all the languages. It then probably looks to see if it was deleted from all the languages upon delete before getting rid of the image file itself (the file in wp-content/uploads folder)