# How to remove files from Wordpress Media Library with PHP on frontend

Tags: php, html, wordpress, frontend, media-library

Sources I've checked to create current code, I have looked up this question and have not found the answer:
[https://kellenmace.com/get-uploads-directory-path-in-wordpress/#:~:text=The%20following%20function%20can%20be%20used%20to%20get,%2A%20%2A%20%40return%20string%20The%20uploads%20directory%20path.](https://kellenmace.com/get-uploads-directory-path-in-wordpress/#:%7E:text=The%20following%20function%20can%20be%20used%20to%20get,%2A%20%2A%20%40return%20string%20The%20uploads%20directory%20path.)

[https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_file/#:~:text=%24file_path%20%3D%20%22%2Fhome%2Fpublic_html%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2020%2F04%2Fphoto_img_1-8.png%22%20%2F%2F%20path%20of%20the%20file,%2F%2Fdelete%20file%20here.%20Log%20in%20to%20add%20feedback](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_file/#:%7E:text=%24file_path%20%3D%20%22%2Fhome%2Fpublic_html%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2020%2F04%2Fphoto_img_1-8.png%22%20%2F%2F%20path%20of%20the%20file,%2F%2Fdelete%20file%20here.%20Log%20in%20to%20add%20feedback)

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/262284/media-not-actually-deleted-on-disk-when-click-permanent-delete

[Deleting files from Media doesn't delete it from uploads folder in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257968/deleting-files-from-media-doesnt-delete-it-from-uploads-folder-in-wordpress)

I am creating a management system for files. The admin will not have access to my Wordpress admin area, they will be able to access a password protected page with HTML forms that use PHP snippets to let them manage their files.

I am currently trying to let the user delete files. I have looked at MANY sources and made the code work to a certain point. It allows the user to type in a file name and it will delete its information in the database, and it will delete it from the wp-content/uploads folder.

```
<html>
    <body>
        Name of file to delete:
        <form method="post">
            <input type=text name="t1">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type=submit name="submission" value="Delete File">
   <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submission'])){

            $db = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
            $entry = $_POST['t1']; //accessing value from the text field
        
            $found = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE name = \"$entry\";";
            $result = $table->query($found);
        
            if($result != 0){
                $delete_file = "DELETE FROM files WHERE name=(\"$entry\");";
                $file_path = get_wordpress_uploads_directory_path().$entry;
                $eq_files->query($delete_file);
                wp_delete_file( $file_path );
                echo "The file deleted is: ".$entry; //displaying result
            }
            else{
                echo "Error. This file does currently not exist in the database.";
            }
        }
?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This currently works as intended! The issue is that it removes the file from the uploads folder and the database, but it does **NOT** remove the file from the Media Library in the Admin area.

The final question: What can I use in PHP to put on the frontend that would allow me to delete a file from the Media Library tab on the Wordpress Admin area?

Answer (score 0):

I found a function that is working.

```
<?php function delete_404_attachments(){ $attachments = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'fields' => 'ids' )); if ($attachments) { foreach ($attachments as $attachmentID){ $file_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachmentID); $file_headers = @get_headers($file_url); if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') { $deleted = wp_delete_attachment($attachmentID, true); } } } } ?>
```

Should I delete my question?